# Can't connect on Win7 via PuTTY

Tags: windows-7, connection, putty

Trying to connect to my VDS from Windows 7 machine.

From server side everything seems to be Ok, but I constantly get 'Network Error. Connection refused'.

It seems to me that either port 22 or PuTTY on local machine is blocked by our corporate network firewall.

What can I do now to resolve the problem?

I certainly will be able to change default port for SSH daemon.

Answer (score 0):

The password to log in to the VDS may have expired. Try resetting it.